# Bizarre location issue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I just saw this in the Careers sidebar on SO:

```
Technical Evangelist
Microsoft Corp Redmond, WA

Senior Software Development Engineer in Test
iyeTek Kalamazoo, MI; San Francisco, CA; Seattle, WA

Software Development Engineer, Platform Tools Team
Amazon Seattle, WA

Web Operations Engineer (DevOps)
PipelineDeals Seattle, WA; Philadelphia, PA

Software Development Engineer - Middleware/Framework
Amazon Seattle, WA

PHP BACKEND DEVELOPER (M/W)
Zalando GmbH Berlin, Germany

More jobs near Bothell...
```

It got my location right (I'm in the Seattle area), but one of these things is not like the others.

Comment: I take the bug is showing a job for a company located in Berlin.

Comment: The bug is clearly Kalamazoo. What a silly name!

Comment: @BenBrocka - It's even better when you say it [Kalamazoozoozoozoozoozoo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFv_PoZ2iP0&t=1m49s).

Comment: Obviously, MasonWheeler is a misbehaving spambot.  Why else would you live in "BotHell"?

Comment: @Jadarnel27: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bothell,_Washington.  It's pronounced like "brothel" without the R, and I don't actually live there, but it's not too far from where I do live.  Probably my Internet traffic is being routed through there by my ISP.

Comment: That is a fantastic explanation of how to pronounce that city's name.

Answer (score 5):

We don't always show you jobs in your area, they just have a much higher probability of showing up.  We do this to make sure you get *some* exposure to jobs in other areas and so jobs in areas without a lot of traffic get some impressions.